# Piecewise highlighting and dim the previous section/text in beamer

Tags: beamer, highlighting

I found a way to piece-wise highlighting in beamer but I also want to dim the previous items as the beamer starts to uncover the newer sections. I have done something like this in powerpoint but stuck on latex beamer. Any help is highly appreciated on how to dim the previous section color.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "section"? Are you referring to section entries in the ToC?

Comment: What I mean is as the beamer starts to uncover the new items, I want to dim the color of the previous items on the same page/frame. I want the audience to focus on the present topic only that I am showing.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\setbeamercovered` together with overlay specifications; a little example (for further details, please refer to Section **17.6 Transparency Effects** of the `beamer` manual):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1> First itemized item.
\item<2> Second itemized item.
\item<3> Third itemized item.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\setbeamercovered{still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},again covered={\opaqueness<1->{10}}}
\begin{frame}
\onslide<1>{Some initial idea.}

\onslide<2>{An interesting development.}

\onslide<3>{An unusual conclusion.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]